# cakephp2 i want to only tweet

Tags: twitter, cakephp-2.0

I use cakephp2.x and use this `Consuming OAuth-enabled APIs with CakePHP` http://code.42dh.com/oauth/
I only want to be able to tweet. But I can't now.

1. Download consuming package and put `app/vender/OAuth`
2. Write this code in PostsController
   `App::import('Vendor', 'OAuth/OAuthClient');`

   > ```
   > public function add() {
   >         $client = $this->createClient();
   >         $requestToken = $client->getRequestToken('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
   > ```
   >
   > 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/lolch/posts');
   >               if ($requestToken) {
   >                   $this->Session->write('twitter_request_token', $requestToken);
   >                   $this->redirect('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token='
   >   . $requestToken->key);
   >               }
   >           }
   >           public function callback() {
   >               $requestToken = $this->Session->read('twitter_request_token');
   >               $client = $this->createClient();
   >               $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
   >   $requestToken);
   >        $client->post($accessToken->key, $accessToken->secret, 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', array('status' =>
   >   'hello world!'));
   >        private function createClient() {
   >               return new OAuthClient('my key', 'my secret');
   >           }

Where should I change the code??

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/LubosRemplik/CakePHP-Twitter-API-Plugin‎ plugin or other twitter plugin for cakephp and read the documentation there to apply what you want. It is easy to use ready made plugin than reinventing the wheel.